# Strange toCharArray() behavior

Tags: java, arrays, char

I was experimenting with `toCharArray()` and found some strange behavior.

Suppose `private static final char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();`

```
 System.out.println(HEX_CHARS);

  /* prints 0123456789abcdef */

 System.out.println("this is HEX_CHARS "+HEX_CHARS); 
  /* prints [C@19821f */
```

Any theoretical reason behind this?

Comment: IF you want to print `char[]`, use `Arrays.toString()` from `java.util.Arrays`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because the parameter to `println` is different in the two calls.

The first parameter is called with `char[]` and the second is called with a string, where `HEX_CHARS` is converted with a call to `.toString()`.

The `println()` have an overriden method that accepts a charArray.

Answer (score 4):

The first line calls the method

```
print(char[] s)
```

on the PrintStream which prints what you expect.  The second one calls the method

```
print(String s)
```

Where is concatenating the string with the toString implementation of the array which is that ugly thing you get ([C@19821f).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects, and its toString methods returns

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

In your case `[C@19821f` means char[] and @`19821f` is its hashcode in hex notation.

If you want to print values from that array use iteration or `Arrays.toString` method.

```
`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(HEX_CHARS));`
```

Answer (score 0):

The strange output is the toString() of the `char[]` type.  for some odd reason, java decided to have a useless default implementation of toString() on array types.  try `Arrays.toString(HEX_STRING)` instead.